# __attribute__((constructor)) equivalent in VC?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I was wondering if it's possible to use C constructors in VC just as it is possible to use them in GCC.
The gcc way is quite straight using the `__attribute__` keyword, unfortunately VC doesn't seem to even know this keyword, as I'm not a Win32 programmer I wonder if there's some sort of equivalent keyword for such things.
Just to note - this is a C program, not a C++ or C# even, (as 'twas quite easy to do that in those languages)

Comment: for those of us who haven't used it, what does it do? (And what do you need it for?)

Comment: Any function marked as `constructor` is run by the dynamic linker as it loads the object.

Comment: @:Jalf: [How exactly does attribute constructor work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work)

Answer (score 49):

Below C code demonstrates how to define a void(void) function to be called at program/library load time, before main executes.

For MSVC, this places a pointer to the function in the user initializer section (.CRT$XCU), basically the same thing the compiler does for the constructor calls for static C++ objects. For GCC, uses a constructor attribute.

```
    // Initializer/finalizer sample for MSVC and GCC/Clang.
    // 2010-2016 Joe Lowe. Released into the public domain.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define INITIALIZER(f) \
        static void f(void); \
        struct f##_t_ { f##_t_(void) { f(); } }; static f##_t_ f##_; \
        static void f(void)
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #pragma section(".CRT$XCU",read)
    #define INITIALIZER2_(f,p) \
        static void f(void); \
        __declspec(allocate(".CRT$XCU")) void (*f##_)(void) = f; \
        __pragma(comment(linker,"/include:" p #f "_")) \
        static void f(void)
    #ifdef _WIN64
        #define INITIALIZER(f) INITIALIZER2_(f,"")
    #else
        #define INITIALIZER(f) INITIALIZER2_(f,"_")
    #endif
#else
    #define INITIALIZER(f) \
        static void f(void) __attribute__((constructor)); \
        static void f(void)
#endif

static void finalize(void)
{
    printf( "finalize\n");
}

INITIALIZER( initialize)
{
    printf( "initialize\n");
    atexit( finalize);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf( "main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe: great post! I really need the tricks for working with VC. It's critical to auto-register a unit test function in C(not C++).

BTW: There should be a tailing \ in the second line of macro INITIALIZER

Comment: Such constuctors will be optimized out in new Visual Studio release builds. Its rerely known and unfortunately unsolved bug. The only workaround I found so far: Project properties > C / C++ > Optimization > Whole Program Optimization(/ GL) must be disabled.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as described above so don't just copy paste above code assuming it will just work.

Comment: GLib recently switched from using `.CRT$XCU` section to using `DllMain` for this reason: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=752837

Comment: @user3042599. Thanks for the heads up on the issues with MSVC 2015 link-time optimizations. I have edited the code sample and it should not have issues, though it now requires MSVC 2008 or later due to use of __pragma() .

Comment: Hi, sorry to resurrect an old thread... I have this same issue, the function is:

` void __attribute__((constructor)) init() {
    // Setup GPU Memory Management
    cuda::gpu_mat_allocator = new cuda::Allocator();
    // cv::cuda::GpuMat::setDefaultAllocator(cuda::gpu_mat_allocator);
  }`

I have used the above sample, with:

`  INITIALIZER(initialize)
  {
   cuda::gpu_mat_allocator = new cuda::Allocator();
   atexit(finalize);
  }`

is that correct?

Comment: Just as a wee, tiny, nigh insignificant little niggle, I'd suggest changing `__attribute__((constructor))` to `__attribute__((__constructor__))`. This is a macro here, so there's no convenience lost this way, and it avoids the theoretical possibility of some lunatic defining `constructor` to something else. Obviously defining `__constructor__` to something stupid would be non-compliant, so it's safer.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably interested in [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: It must be executed _before_ entering main(), that's for dlls, how's that related ? :/

Comment: About the only real use people have for __attribute__((constructor)) is to use them in shared libraries similar to emulate a  DllMain :)

Comment: `__attribute__((constructor))` is useful even in a single program image; for example, inserting global hooks around library and system calls, or registering built-in "plugins", or initializing data structures that dynamically linked modules will need in their "`DllMain`"-alikes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a way to avoid using C++ features with MSVC.  (MSVC's C support sucks anyways.)

Untested, but this should at least allow the same code to work in both MSVC and GCC.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
struct construct { construct(void (*f)(void)) { f(); } };
#define constructor(fn) \
    void fn(void); static constructor constructor_##fn(fn)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#define constructor(fn)
    void fn(void) __attribute__((constructor))
#endif

static constructor(foo);
void foo() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this does not work in plain C on MSVC 2013 or 2015. Seems like C compiler mode doesnt support constructors in a struct. I tried to make it work in various ways.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the last answer in MSVC like

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma section(".CRT$XCU",read)
#define INITIALIZER2_(f,p) \
        static void f(void); \
        __declspec(allocate(".CRT$XCU")) void (*f##_)(void) = f; \
        __pragma(comment(linker,"/include:" p #f "_")) \
        static void f(void)
#ifdef _WIN64
#define INITIALIZER(f) INITIALIZER2_(f,"")
#else
#define INITIALIZER(f) INITIALIZER2_(f,"_")
#endif
#else
#define INITIALIZER(f) \
        static void f(void) __attribute__((constructor)); \
        static void f(void)
#endif
```

but INITIALIZER(f) can't appear in 2 different files with the same function name passed to INITIALIZER, the following definition will allow that

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define INITIALIZER(f) \
    static void f();\
    static int __f1(){f();return 0;}\
    __pragma(data_seg(".CRT$XIU"))\
    static int(*__f2) () = __f1;\
    __pragma(data_seg())\
    static void f()
#else
#define INITIALIZER(f) \
    __attribute__((constructor)) static void f()
#endif
```

Comment: The linker pragma in my answer is needed, and does have the effect that initializer function names must be unique for the whole exe/dll. See the comments under my example by user3042599, and my response.

I am unaware if the change of section name is an alternate solution to the linker pragma, but it will have other side effects.