# can static linking result in executing some init routines?

Tags: c++, c, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

do not understand this thing: I got a program in c 
and I am linking some second party static libs to that
(as far as I know lhis libs can be also some wrappers on 
dlls) - does it can bring my program to 'implicitely' (I mean 
without explicit call to that in my code) run some 
initialisation code from whithin those libs (that will
execute before my main() routine ? - or it cannot ?)

I am asking here about about c code (eventualy about c
code without any c++ feature but compiled in c++ mode
by c++ compiler - linked static libs can be written in 
any language)

tnx for answer

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: windows, and I eventualy use many compilers gcc, vc, icc, mingw and other too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your platform.

If you use GCC, you can have function declared with `__attribute__((constructor))`. This function **WILL** be called before your main, even from dynamic library.

```
__attribute__((constructor))
void my_init()
{
    /* do stuff; */
}
```

You can find more details in [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) and in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work)

There's some way how to do it in VC as well, even though not as simple. (See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113409/attribute-constructor-equivalent-in-vc))

**EDIT**: If you link to some third party library, it may call some init function. Even if the library is in C. And there's no portable  and generic way, how to detect it. And you probably don't want to mess with that as the library may depend it it being called before main starts.

If you really want to find out if it calls something, you'd have to look inside the binary.
In ELF files, there's a section `.init_array` containing "pointers" to functions that will be invoked at start and it can be dumped using objdump (`objdump -s -j .init_array <binary>`)

I assume there's similar section in PE files in windows, but I never worked with those, sorry.

**EDIT2**:
The `main()` function starts your code. But there's stuff to do even before it's executed. When you compile your program, the compiler adds some code that is executed before the `main()` and initializes environment for program (stack, C library...).

Under Linux this will be provided mainly by functions `_start` and `_init`. And as a feature, you can instruct it the compiler to call some your function(s) as well, inside the `_init` function.

Dynamic library won't have the `_start` function, but there's still `_init` that will be called when the library's loaded. And a call to some user function can be included there as well.

In the case of static library it gets a bit more complicated, as the linker may remove some functions, when they're never called from you program. But once it's called (even indirectly from the library code) or just referenced somewhere in the library and never actually called, it will end up in you binary and will be called before `main()`.

Some info about `_start` and `_init` can be [found here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/_start-_init-and-frame_dummy-functions-810257/).

Under windows the compiler and linker is different, but it should work in a similar way.

Comment: I am asking from perspective of main program coder using external libs - so can i be sure that linked lib inits are not called or I can suspect they are - Is there a way to check it?

Comment: If the implementation is a conforming C++ implementation, constructors for all objects used in the program, including those in library files, must be called before `main` starts. I can imagine Windows having conformance bugs here like it does in most other places, but if you're using gcc or icc rather than MSVC, I really doubt they would get something this important wrong.

Comment: I am speaking more about c program (but compiled in c++ mode) and linking many small c-like libraries - what with that?, will they call inits or not? - I do not understand your answer :C

Comment: See the edited answer. TL;DR: Initialization code may get called, even before your main().

Comment: sadly i do not fully understand how it works and why it is called even in c

Comment: I edited the answer to explain how it works, hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Linked libs of any sort can't run initialisation code without an explicit call from your code in either c or c++.

Comment: This is not true in general.

Comment: If it has global variables in it might. But no one would use global variables, ever, right?

Comment: you above, probably are talking about c++ linked with c++ libs, what with c program linked with c libs, c program linked with c++ libs, can this involve fireing implicit initialisations also ?

Comment: I am also asking about c code compiled in c++ mode becouse this is what i really use

Comment: You should not be compiling C using a C++ compiler, because there are various constructs that are subtly different between the two languages. Doesn't your compiler have a C mode?