# __attribute__((destructor)) equivalent in VC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I've looked at [__attribute__((constructor)) equivalent in VC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113409/attribute-constructor-equivalent-in-vc) and [CRT Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918180.aspx), which were both helpful regarding the gcc-specific `__attribute__((constructor))`. But what about `__attribute__((destructor))`? Is there a VC equivalent?

Comment: the answer you linked gives an equivalent functionality, with the use of atexit See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tze57ck3.aspx

Comment: In case of libraries - there is very little you can do safely in `DllMain` (read: call functions of Kernel32.dll as long as they are not loading libraries - and practically nothing else). Unfortunately other methods (`atexit` etc.) are not much better as they tend to be implemented via `DllMain`. In such cases the rewrite of code tend to be the easy option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making a dynamic link library, you can make your [DllMain entry point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handle this:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        // equivalent of __attribute__((constructor))...

        // return TRUE if succeeded, FALSE if you failed to initialize properly
        return TRUE; // I'm assuming you succeeded.
    }
    else if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        // equivalent of __attribute__((destructor))...
    }

    // Return value is ignored when fdwReason isn't DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, so we'll
    // just return TRUE.
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Interesting and actually seems more clear than gcc's `__attribute__`. I'll heed the warnings about `DllMain` and see what I can do. Thanks!