# How to define a function and use it in one macro?

Tags: c, macros

I need to define an event handler and then to add it to an array of handlers at a certain index. The handler will never be called by its real name, so I want to handle both the definition and the assignment in one place. A good solution would look like this:

```
MAKE_HANDLER(evet_code, my_event) {
    //handle the event
}
```

My naive solution was to have this expand into

```
void on_my_event(event* ev);
array_of_handlers[event_code] = &on_my_event;
void on_my_event(event* ev) {
    //handle the event
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, since an assignment cannot occur in global scope (except for initialization by constant). I am aware that I could have one macro define the function and another assign it in main, however this would be a duplication of information and very tedious to work with, when I have many handlers. What other solutions are there?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] since an assignment cannot occur in global scope [...]

You could use a [constructor (search in this page)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) to run the assignment code on startup, without cluttering your main function:

```
void on_my_event(event* ev);
void on_my_event_constructor(void)  __attribute__((constructor));
void on_my_event_constructor(void) {
  array_of_handlers[event_code] = &on_my_event;
}
void on_my_event(event* ev) {
    //handle the event
}
```

Though this is in no way portable. (But works in GCC and clang, and  [apparently with some hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390626/1116364) in MSVC, too.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file, for example handlers.inc and put all your macro calls there:

```
MAKE_HANDLER(a,b)
MAKE_HANDLER(c,d)
MAKE_HANDLER(e,f)
```

When you use it, do the following:

```
#define MAKE_HANDLER(evet_code, my_event) .....
#include "handlers.inc"
#undef MAKE_HANDLER
```

define MAKE_HANDLER in the global scope just to the declarations and definitions. And inside the initialization function do just the initialization.

Comment: My include file would contain `MAKE_HANDLER(a,b) { and some code }` instead. I guess in main I could do `#define MAKE_HANDLER(a,b) handlers[a]=...; if (false)` to ignore the function bodies...

Comment: If you really need code there, it will become trickier, although still possible. If you add parentheses around the code, it can be a macro parameter. Or you can surround the code with something like `#ifdef IMPLEMENTATION`. But it might be easier if you generate your code.