# MSVC equivalent for: void __attribute__((constructor))

Tags: c++

I am trying to port a GCC function to MSVC, and am stuck at this code:

```
 void __attribute__((constructor)) init() {
    // Setup GPU Memory Management
    cuda::gpu_mat_allocator = new cuda::Allocator();
  }
```

this answer is similar, but I do not understand it. 
[__attribute__((constructor)) equivalent in VC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113409/attribute-constructor-equivalent-in-vc)

Is the answer posted there, my answer too? Or is there a simpler way? thank you.

Comment: This is literally the same question. There's no point in asking it again; you'll get the same answers...

Comment: understood. thank you. i was hoping for some clarity, but i will do my research instead! :)

Comment: If you want clarity, you will have to tell us what you need clarity on exactly.

Comment: (You could offer a bounty on the original question for a better/clearer answer)