# How can I securely implement a set of C functions as a self-initializing library?

Tags: c, security, initialization, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have never been able to find any clear, concise and complete explanations on the creation and use of libraries in C; both dynamic/shared and static.

For a couple of reasons, I would like to implement some of my C header files for a project I am working on as libraries. Each library may have a global structure acting as a namespace for static functions in the headers, and an entry function to initialize this structure.

```
struct mylibrary {
    int (*function1)(void);
    int (*function2)(void);
} mylibrary;

static int my_library_function_1 (void) {
    return 1;
}

static int my_library_function_2 (void) {
    return 2;
}

void entry_mylibrary (void) {
    mylibrary.function1 = my_library_function_1;
    mylibrary.function2 = my_library_function_2;
}
```

As I understand it, this should work without a problem with a static library. All I have to do is link the library and call the function `entry_mylibrary` from elsewhere in my program. However, I would like my libraries to be self-initializing; that is, I want the entry function to be called when the code is loaded. As I understand it, that is the domain of shared libraries, which can declare entry points to be executed when the library is loaded.

So why don't I simply create dynamic libraries?

Well, I am worried about application security. If I am just linking a library at runtime, I don't see what is to prevent some end user from swapping my library for their own. Could I not create a new library declaring the same variables as the old one, and swap the definitions of these variables for my own? I don't see why the executable would care.

I suppose then that my questions are:

- Is there some obscure method to self-initializing a static library?
- How can I verify that the (shared) library I load is indeed MY library?

I am/will be working cross platform. 64 bit Windows and Linux. Apple products are to-be-determined, but not a priority.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community on Windows 10. I will be using GCC for linux. I will be implementing the same libraries on all platforms with platform compilers, e.g. VS 2017 on Windows and GCC on linux; I won't be cross-compiling platform-specific code.

Comment: Too broad. The self-initialization question is unconnected with the security
question. The former is a straightforward enough question. The latter likely
stems from the spurious general fears that beginners usually have about making shared libraries,
and calls for an off-putting investment in explication. Suggest you excise that
question and make it a separate one if you like.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I could have written a shared library. If I did, however, ship my application right now with a shared library, anybody could swap the library for their own version of it. It's no different than swapping the file in development. I would call that a critical bug more so than a spurious general fear. You're right, though, in that the security topic is disconnected from library initialization, so I might write a separate question about library security. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some obscure method to self-initializing a static library?

With GCC it is not obscure: just use `__attribute__((constructor))`.  With MSVC it's a bit harder, but still possible: [__attribute__((constructor)) equivalent in VC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113409/attribute-constructor-equivalent-in-vc)

> How can I verify that the (shared) library I load is indeed MY library?

With the above you won't need to use a shared library.