# How to portably load dynamic libraries and run their initialization code?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, portability

I'm used to using the `dl_open()` library function to dynamically load a shared-object/DLL:

```
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flags);
```

... and this also runs all functions which, in the ELF format, are marked with `.init`; or in the C/C++ code, are marked with `__attribute__((constructor))` :

[How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work#2053078)

However - I can only be sure this works using GCC and on GNU/Linux (and perhaps wherever `glibc` is available).

My question is: How can I do the same in a more portable way? I'm interested in portability both to other compilers and other platforms.

Note: I marked this C++ because that's what I'm using, but obviously a C-ish solution in acceptable - as what I've described above is a C-ish solution.

Comment: boost has [dll module](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html) but I am not sure if it fits your "portability".

Comment: @LouisGo: It's something. Care to make it into an answer? It would be even better if you could describe how it works on different platforms.

Answer (score 5):

### Initializing when library loaded

Edit: Revisited the question again and I found that I didn't answer the initialization part.

The best answer I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390626/4123703) one which is still platform dependent. Will update if there is a better one.

### For platform specific

In windows it's [DllMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but be sure to read the part of [Dynamic link library best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) to see what's unsafe to call in `DllMain`

In linux:

```
__attribute__ ((constructor))
__attribute__ ((destructor))
```

### Load library portably

Since Boost is available on many platforms, its [_dll module](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll.html) might be considered as cross platform. Though compilation for different platforms are required.

Following is the [basic example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.plugin_basics) for Boost.Dll by importing a single variable in plugin.

Header

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <string>

class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE my_plugin_api {
public:
   virtual std::string name() const = 0;
   virtual float calculate(float x, float y) = 0;

   virtual ~my_plugin_api() {}
};
```

Source

```
#include <boost/config.hpp> // for BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT
#include "../tutorial_common/my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace my_namespace {

class my_plugin_sum : public my_plugin_api {
public:
    my_plugin_sum() {
        std::cout << "Constructing my_plugin_sum" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string name() const {
        return "sum";
    }

    float calculate(float x, float y) {
        return x + y;
    }

    ~my_plugin_sum() {
        std::cout << "Destructing my_plugin_sum ;o)" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Exporting `my_namespace::plugin` variable with alias name `plugin`
// (Has the same effect as `BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(my_namespace::plugin, plugin)`)
extern "C" BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT my_plugin_sum plugin;
my_plugin_sum plugin;

} // namespace my_namespace
```

Usage: note that [append_decorations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/dll/load_mode/type.html) is the way for seeking platform specific naming convention.

Eg: libplugin.so on linux or plugin.dll on windows.

```
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp> // for import_alias
#include <iostream>
#include "../tutorial_common/my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace dll = boost::dll;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    boost::dll::fs::path lib_path(argv[1]);             // argv[1] contains path to directory with our plugin library
    boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_api> plugin;            // variable to hold a pointer to plugin variable
    std::cout << "Loading the plugin" << std::endl;

    plugin = dll::import<my_plugin_api>(          // type of imported symbol is located between `<` and `>`
        lib_path / "my_plugin_sum",                     // path to the library and library name
        "plugin",                                       // name of the symbol to import
        dll::load_mode::append_decorations              // makes `libmy_plugin_sum.so` or `my_plugin_sum.dll` from `my_plugin_sum`
    );

    std::cout << "plugin->calculate(1.5, 1.5) call:  " << plugin->calculate(1.5, 1.5) << std::endl;
}
```

---

To create an object from plugin, here's the [factory example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.factory_method_in_plugin).
First, make a factory method returns `boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_aggregator>`.

```
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp> // for BOOST_DLL_ALIAS   
#include "../tutorial_common/my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace my_namespace {

class my_plugin_aggregator : public my_plugin_api {
    float aggr_;
    my_plugin_aggregator() : aggr_(0) {}

public:
    std::string name() const {
        return "aggregator";
    }

    float calculate(float x, float y) {
        aggr_ += x + y;
        return aggr_;
    }

    // Factory method
    static boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_aggregator> create() {
        return boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_aggregator>(
            new my_plugin_aggregator()
        );
    }
};


BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(
    my_namespace::my_plugin_aggregator::create, // <-- this function is exported with...
    create_plugin                               // <-- ...this alias name
)

} // namespace my_namespace
```

Load creator method and create object.

```
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp> // for import_alias
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "../tutorial_common/my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace dll = boost::dll;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    boost::dll::fs::path shared_library_path(argv[1]);                  // argv[1] contains path to directory with our plugin library
    shared_library_path /= "my_plugin_aggregator";
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_api> (pluginapi_create_t)();
    boost::function<pluginapi_create_t> creator;

    creator = boost::dll::import_alias<pluginapi_create_t>(             // type of imported symbol must be explicitly specified
        shared_library_path,                                            // path to library
        "create_plugin",                                                // symbol to import
        dll::load_mode::append_decorations                              // do append extensions and prefixes
    );

    boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_api> plugin = creator();
    std::cout << "plugin->calculate(1.5, 1.5) call:  " << plugin->calculate(1.5, 1.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "plugin->calculate(1.5, 1.5) second call:  " << plugin->calculate(1.5, 1.5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Plugin Name:  " << plugin->name() << std::endl;
}
```

Note: When `creator` is destroyed, dynamic library is unloaded as well. Dereferencing `plugin` after library unloaded is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What about a mechanism for running initialization code?

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks for the suggestion. It makes the answer more complete. Though I wish there is another answer for loading cross platform dynamic library other than boost.

Comment: Suggest renaming `my_plugin_aggregator` into something like `adder` or `adder_plugin`. The current name indicates that the aggregator aggregates plugins.

Comment: Also, I still don't see you running initialization code...

Comment: @einpoklum Example code is copied from document ation of boost so I keep it as is. Could you elaborate on "a mechanism for running initialization code"? I thought you meant how to create an object from dynamic library but it seems I understood it in a wrong way.