# store or check value of getenv() only once in a shared library/DLL

Tags: c, dll, strcmp, getenv

I have a function to print debug logs which has to be toggled depending on the environment variable. Instead of checking the env var each time the `print_trace()` is called, what should be the best method to store it and reuse that value?

```
void print_trace(const char* msg)
{
    const char* s = getenv("DEBUG_TRACE");

    if(!strcmp(s,"ON"))
      printf(msg);
}
```

There is no `main()` as this is a shared library.

Comment: `'ON'`? Shouldn't it be `"ON"`?

Comment: Also, remember that `strcmp` returns `0` (i.e. *false*) if the strings are equal.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks, updated it.

Comment: Lastly about your problem: Almost all dynamic libraries will have some kind of on-load function, which can be used to do some initialization. How this works depends on your operating system, of course. If you want a portable solution, add an "init" function which is used to initialize the library and must be called early in program execution.

Comment: `getenv()` may return `NULL` in case of errors. Add `if (s == NULL) { return; }` as a check before the `strcmp()`.

Comment: You can create a function which is called once when your library is loaded by using  [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), or look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113409/attribute-constructor-equivalent-in-vc) for some pointers of how to do this in MSVC. Barmar's answer is the best way to do it cross-platform, although it might call `getenv()` multiple times if you have multiple threads calling `print_trace()` simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could save the result of the decision in a static variable.

```
void print_trace(const char* msg)
{
    static int debug_on = -1; // -1 == not yet set
    if (debug_on == -1) {
        const char* s = getenv("DEBUG_TRACE");
        debug_on = s && (strcmp(s, "ON") == 0);
    }

    if(debug_on)
      printf("%s", msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the thread safe [`call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/call_once) feature that was added in C11.

Example:

```c
#include <threads.h>

static bool debug_mode;                   // your debug mode flag

void set_debug_mode(void) {               // this is only called once
    const char *s = getenv("DEBUG_TRACE");
    debug_mode = s && !strcmp(s, "ON");
}

void print_trace(const char* msg) {
    static once_flag flag = ONCE_FLAG_INIT;
    call_once(&flag, set_debug_mode);     // called once to set debug_mode

    if(debug_mode)
        printf(msg);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that is a synchronization feature. `call_once` guarantees synchronization between multiple threads, so it has some costs of locking or other synchronization. Its purpose is to ensure that, when multiple threads might attempt something at the same time, only one occurs. That is overkill for OP’s request, where there is no stated need for synchronization, and a simple static flag suffices.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It may be overkill, not sure. I'll leave it here as an alternative that may be worth looking into.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If it's only used once in the entire program run, the locking overhead should be negligible.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure how it's implemented but I expect an atomic bool to be checked for every call to `print_trace`. I think locking will only have to be done if the atomic bool is not set (that is, on the first call). [This](https://godbolt.org/z/4YovEoT3z) is how I imagine it. Not sure if there's anything else needed though.